# HTML-BROWSER ZOOM CAUSES ALIGNMENT PROBLEMS

Tags: html

I have 2 div elements with float left and float right withiin a div element..when i zoom the browser,all the  alignment changes..the zooming should be like...how we zoom an image....can anyone give suggestions to resolve this problem

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
div.advancedDrugSearchOuterLayout
{
border-style: groove;
border-color: #005ce5;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
margin-top:1%;
height: 430px;
zoom: 200%;
}
div.searchByBlock{
border-style: ridge;
border-color: #000;
float: left;
height: 70%;
width: 46%;
margin-left: 2%;
margin-top:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}
div.narrowByBlock{
border-style: ridge;
border-color: #000;
float: right;
height: 70%;
width: 46%;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-top:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}
div.searchByText{
margin-left: 2%;
float:left;
text-align:left;
width:46%;
}
div.narrowByText{
margin-right: 1.5%;
float:right;
text-align:left;
width:46%;
}
div.compareAndClearFields{
margin-left: 2%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:46%;
}
div.errorMessageDisplayforAdvanceDrugSearch{
margin-left: 2%;
float:right;
text-align:center;
width:46%;
}
div.advancedDrugSearchText{
margin-left: 2%;
}
div.textBelowAdvancedDrugSearchText{
margin-left: 2%;
}
div.browseClassesLink{
float:right;
}
input.search{
background-color: #007fea;
height:30px;
width:40%;
font: bold;
font-color: white;
margin-left: 3%;
}
table.blocksForSearchByAndNarrowBy{
margin-bottom:3%;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="claro">

<div class="advancedDrugSearchOuterLayout">
    <div class="advancedDrugSearchText">
        <font size="4" color= "mediumorchid"><b>THIS iS AN EXAMPLE</b></font>
     </div>
     <div class="textBelowAdvancedDrugSearchText">
         <font size="3" ><i>THESE ARE DATABASE TEXT</a>
      </div>

    <div>
       <div class="searchByText"> 
            <font size="2"><u><b>searchBy</b><i>SearchTermIsrequired</i></u></font>
       </div>
       <div class="narrowByText">
            <font size="2"><u><b>narrow</b><i>(optional)</i></u></font>
       </div>
    </div>   


    <div class="searchByBlock">

    <table border="1"">
        <tr><td style="width:100px"></td>
            <td><div style="float:right"><a href="#">Browse list of classes</div>
        </td></tr>
        </table>    
<div>       
        <div style="float:left">
            <font size="3">drugClass</font>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right">   
            <input  id="selectDrugClasses">
         </div> 
</div> 
        <div>       
            <table>     
                <tr>
                    <td height="110"></td>
                    <td height="110"></td>
                 </tr>      
            </table>
        </div>  
        <div>       
             <div style="float:left">
                     <font size="3">CLASS</font>
                  </div>                    
                  <div style="float:right">
                           <input id="selectIndications">
                    </div>      
        </div>
    </div>     

    <div class="narrowByBlock">
    <table><tr><td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td> <div style="float:right"><input type="radio" checked="true">include
            <input type="radio">exclude
         </div> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>         

        <div style="float:left">
                               <font size="3">CLINICAL</font>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right">   
                              <input id="selectAdverseEffects">                              
        </div>  
        <div>
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td height="90"></td>
                <td height="90"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table border="1"><tr><td style="width:10px"></td>
    <td><div  style="float:right">      

            <input type="radio"  checked="true">include
            <input type="radio">exclude

    </div></td></tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <div style="float:left">
                             <font size="3">Suggestion</font>
        </div>
            <div style="float:right">
                                 <input id="selectDrugInteractions">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div class="compareAndClearFields">
                <input class="search" type="submit" value="Search & Compare Drugs" name="submit" id="formSubmit" onClick="submitForm()"> 
                <a onClick="resetForm()">clearAllFields</a>
       </div>

    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you want it be zoomed?

Comment: Zooming must not cause alignment problems,,that was the requirement..because when you see w3 school sites no matter how much we zoom,,,no alignment willl change..it will be like zooming an image..likewise..this html design should also follow that when zooming

Comment: set the `width` and `height` in `px` (not `%`), or you can set them in `%` from defined size.

Comment: Tried Rinaldi..it Dint work

Comment: but it works with me :D

Comment: can you show the code you edited

Comment: if you set them in percent(`%`), the `width` and `height` would have their sizes depend on window size

Comment: I'm sorry, I got a pray last hour. So, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add a `div` that has a solid size. 
Here's mine, and may be it's what you wonder :

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.allbody{
width : 1024px;
height: auto;
margin: 0px auto;
}
div.advancedDrugSearchOuterLayout
{
border-style: groove;
border-color: #005ce5;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
margin-top:1%;
height: 430px;
zoom: 200%;
}
div.searchByBlock{
border-style: ridge;
border-color: #000;
float: left;
height: 70%;
width: 46%;
margin-left: 2%;
margin-top:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}
div.narrowByBlock{
border-style: ridge;
border-color: #000;
float: right;
height: 70%;
width: 46%;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-top:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}
div.searchByText{
margin-left: 2%;
float:left;
text-align:left;
width:46%;
}
div.narrowByText{
margin-right: 1.5%;
float:right;
text-align:left;
width:46%;
}
div.compareAndClearFields{
margin-left: 2%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:46%;
}
div.errorMessageDisplayforAdvanceDrugSearch{
margin-left: 2%;
float:right;
text-align:center;
width:46%;
}
div.advancedDrugSearchText{
margin-left: 2%;
}
div.textBelowAdvancedDrugSearchText{
margin-left: 2%;
}
div.browseClassesLink{
float:right;
}
input.search{
background-color: #007fea;
height:30px;
width:40%;
font: bold;
font-color: white;
margin-left: 3%;
}
table.blocksForSearchByAndNarrowBy{
margin-bottom:3%;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="allbody">
<div class="claro">

<div class="advancedDrugSearchOuterLayout">
    <div class="advancedDrugSearchText">
        <font size="4" color= "mediumorchid"><b>THIS iS AN EXAMPLE</b></font>
     </div>
     <div class="textBelowAdvancedDrugSearchText">
         <font size="3" ><i>THESE ARE DATABASE TEXT</a>
      </div>

    <div>
       <div class="searchByText"> 
            <font size="2"><u><b>searchBy</b><i>SearchTermIsrequired</i></u></font>
       </div>
       <div class="narrowByText">
            <font size="2"><u><b>narrow</b><i>(optional)</i></u></font>
       </div>
    </div>   


    <div class="searchByBlock">

    <table border="1"">
        <tr><td style="width:100px"></td>
            <td><div style="float:right"><a href="#">Browse list of classes</div>
        </td></tr>
        </table>    
<div>       
        <div style="float:left">
            <font size="3">drugClass</font>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right">   
            <input  id="selectDrugClasses">
         </div> 
</div> 
        <div>       
            <table>     
                <tr>
                    <td height="110"></td>
                    <td height="110"></td>
                 </tr>      
            </table>
        </div>  
        <div>       
             <div style="float:left">
                     <font size="3">CLASS</font>
                  </div>                    
                  <div style="float:right">
                           <input id="selectIndications">
                    </div>      
        </div>
    </div>     

    <div class="narrowByBlock">
    <table><tr><td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td> <div style="float:right"><input type="radio" checked="true">include
            <input type="radio">exclude
         </div> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>         

        <div style="float:left">
                               <font size="3">CLINICAL</font>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right">   
                              <input id="selectAdverseEffects">                              
        </div>  
        <div>
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td height="90"></td>
                <td height="90"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table border="1"><tr><td style="width:10px"></td>
    <td><div  style="float:right">      

            <input type="radio"  checked="true">include
            <input type="radio">exclude

    </div></td></tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <div style="float:left">
                             <font size="3">Suggestion</font>
        </div>
            <div style="float:right">
                                 <input id="selectDrugInteractions">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div class="compareAndClearFields">
                <input class="search" type="submit" value="Search & Compare Drugs" name="submit" id="formSubmit" onClick="submitForm()"> 
                <a onClick="resetForm()">clearAllFields</a>
       </div>

    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can limit the impact of alignment fail to a certain extend using css styling. If you intention is to make the page dynamically re align with zooming. I prefer you to make it an Responsive design. Use Boot Strap it is a powerful tool which can solve these issues.

Just as a temporary fix change these styles

```
div.searchByBlock {
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: ridge;
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    margin: 1% 1% 1% 2%;
    width: 45%;
}

div.narrowByBlock {
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: ridge;
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    margin: 1% 2%;
    width: 45%;
}

div.advancedDrugSearchOuterLayout {
    border-color: #005CE5;
    border-style: groove;
    float: left;
    height: 430px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Yes it controlled to some extent when zooming...how to use bootstrap?

Comment: Yes AKhil...They style for search by block worked...but not for narrow by block

Comment: Its a frame work for web development. Its very easy to implement. Checkout the site download the package. Just go through the manual.

Comment: As a second option you can use media queries. But which need some effort like create individual design for each resolution and creating different styles for each resolution.

Comment: I corrected only those main boxes which you mentioned on the question.

Comment: Your temporary fix worked for searchby block ..all the elements remained in the same position...but the elements in narrowby block are moving..how to fix it

Comment: :) you have to change all the style and align properly. Its the only method. Anyway the length of the text inside box and headers are expanding. IT wont be that much easy and good looking with css correction.

Comment: Just try and come with new issues you face. You will surely helped. There are a lot of css nerds in stackoverflow so work out hard.